# Why this C# Regular Expression crashes my program?

Tags: c#, regex

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Working
{
    class Program4
    {
        static string errorurl = 
               "http://www.realtor.ca/propertyDetails.aspx?propertyId=8692663";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s;

            s = getWebpageContent(errorurl);

            s = removeNewLineCharacters(s);

            getFields(s);

            Console.WriteLine("End");
        }


        public static void getFields(string html)
        {
            Match m;
            string fsRE = @"ismeasurement.*?>.*?(\d+).*?sqft";
            m = Regex.Match(html, fsRE, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }

        private static string removeNewLineCharacters(string str)
        {
            string[] charsToRemove = new string[] { "\n", "\r" };

            foreach (string c in charsToRemove)
            {
                str = str.Replace(c, "");
            }

            return str;
        }


        static string getWebpageContent(string url)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            client.Headers.Add("user-agent",
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; 
                          .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

            Stream data = client.OpenRead(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            data.Close();
            reader.Close();

            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

This program hangs. It runs correctly when I remove RegexOptions.IgnoreCase option or 
when I remove call to removeNewLineCharacters() function.
Could someone tell me what is going on, please?

Comment: By the way, you program doesn't crash.  It hangs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@"ismeasurement.*?>.*?(\d+).*?sqft"
```

Seeing so many lazy matches, I guess too much time is spent on [backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).

Try to refactor it into not using lazy matches, e.g.

```
@"ismeasurement[^>]*>\D*(\d+)\s*sqft"
```

The reason removing `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` works is because there is only the string "isMeasurement" in that page. The reason removing `removeNewLineCharacters` works is because `.` doesn't match new lines so it can stop early.

(BTW, [why are you matching HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)?)

Comment: Thanks Kenny, you the man!
Why am I using regex to match html? I tried HtmlAgilityPack with this website and regex looked like an easier solution.